# Angular property to reset other property

Tags: angularjs

I have a button named "TRK_9_1_upgrade" that is used to start a process (TRK_9_1_upgrade=1), the signal that the process is started arrives from (TRK_9_1_master_control_enabled=0), I need that when this signal arrives the value of TRK_9_1_upgrade becomes 0.

I've tried with the following code but it is not ok, how I can achieve the right behaviour?

```
<ma-switch-img point="TRK_9_1_upgrade" ng-mousedown="TRK_9_1_upgrade.setValue(!TRK_9_1_upgrade.value)" ng-mouseup="TRK_9_1_upgrade.setValue(TRK_9_1_master_control_enabled.value && TRK_9_1_upgrade.value)"   default-src="./img/emergency-tiny.png" src-map="{'0': './img/off-tiny.png','1': './img/on-tiny.png'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
<md-button ng-if="TRK_9_1_master_control_enabled.value==1" ng-init="TRK_9_1_upgrade.setValue(0)"  ng-click="TRK_9_1_upgrade.setValue(1)" class="md-raised" title="Upgrade">Upgrade</md-button>
    <md-button ng-if="TRK_9_1_master_control_enabled.value==0 && TRK_9_1_upgrade.value==1" class="md-raised md-pressed" title="Upgrading">Upgrading</md-button>
```

I think it is ok because using ng-if when the condition is true for first time it is also called ng-init.